# How to call two functions separately on condition using tkinter buttons?

Tags: python, function, user-interface, button, tkinter

I'm trying to create a basic game in tkinter to get familiar with GUI programming with Python. I'm not trying to make it efficient, hence the copy and paste of the same statement many times. I'm trying to make it so when a user clicks a button it changes the text of the button to either 'X' or 'O' depending on who's turn it is. In my button I have the `command =` followed by my function to change the text to either of the two options. However when I click on one button, the whole grid of buttons changes to that text. So I'm trying to find out if there is something like this I could use:

```
command =  lambda:[placeX() or placeO()]
```

My code is below:

```
import tkinter as tk, sys as s

Startwindow = tk.Tk()
Startwindow.title("Tic-Tac-Toe")
Startwindow.resizable(0,0)
Startwindow.geometry("1200x600")
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Joshua Brown\\Desktop\\tic tac toe\\download.gif")
renderImage = tk.Label(image=image)
renderImage.grid()

def exe():
    print("Game has exited.")
    Startwindow.destroy()
    s.exit("Requested to close.")

def start():
    print("Game window opening...")
    gameWindow = tk.Tk()
    gameWindow.title("Tic-Tac-Toe: Game Window")
    gameWindow.geometry("450x483")
    gameWindow.resizable(0,0)
    Startwindow.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Joshua Brown\Desktop\tic tac toe\tictactoe_H4a_icon.ico')

    board1 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "1", command = lambda:[placeX(), placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    board2 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "2", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    board3 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "3", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board3.grid(row=2, column=0)
    board4 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "4", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board4.grid(row=0, column=1)
    board5 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "5", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board5.grid(row=1, column=1)
    board6 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "6", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board6.grid(row=2, column=1)
    board7 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "7", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board7.grid(row=0, column=2)
    board8 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "8", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board8.grid(row=1, column=2)
    board9 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "9", command = lambda:[placeX(),placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
    board9.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def placeX():
        board1.config(text='X')
        board2.config(text='X')
        board3.config(text='X')
        board4.config(text='X')
        board5.config(text='X')
        board6.config(text='X')
        board7.config(text='X')
        board8.config(text='X')
        board9.config(text='X')


    def placeO():
        board1.config(text='O')
        board2.config(text='O')
        board3.config(text='O')
        board4.config(text='O')
        board5.config(text='O')
        board6.config(text='O')
        board7.config(text='O')
        board8.config(text='O')
        board9.config(text='O')
    gameWindow.mainloop()

    if board1 and board2 and board3 == 'X':
        print("YEAH")


Startwindow.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Joshua Brown\Desktop\tic tac toe\tictactoe_H4a_icon.ico')
startButton = tk.Button(Startwindow, text = "Start Game", command = start, height = 1, width = 20, bg = '#ff3333')
startButton.config(font =("helvectia", 20))
startButton.grid()
exitButton = tk.Button(Startwindow, text = "Exit Game", command = exe, height = 1, width = 20, bg = '#ff3333')
exitButton.config(font =("helvectia", 20))
exitButton.grid()
Startwindow.configure(background = "white")

Startwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: How is your code keeping track of who's turn it is (or how would that be determined)?

Comment: That's a good point, I am doing this backwards I think, which doesn't make much sense I know. I was thinking maybe the easiest way was using the random library and putting them into a list to determine the first go. From there I was hoping that in the command section there would be a way to switch between the two so 1 time function A is called and the next time function B if that was possible?

Comment: I would suggest storing it in a variable (or class instance attribute) for easy access. You can initialize the variable's value anyway you want (such as by using the `random` module). If such a variable existed, you could easily create a `lambda` function for the `command=` argument that does the right thing.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. It seems very easy now I think about it, I feel a bit silly haha. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't use `lambda`. Have the button call a command. Put any logic you want in that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the placeX and placeO functions. You see, all your buttons refer to one function (changeX/changeY) which changes all buttons to either X or Y.

```
def placeX():
    board1.config(text='X') #changes 1st button to x
    board2.config(text='X')
    board3.config(text='X')
    board4.config(text='X')
    board5.config(text='X')
    board6.config(text='X')
    board7.config(text='X')
    board8.config(text='X')
    board9.config(text='X') #and all the rest above it non-selectively, one click = change all
```

Instead what you should have is separate functions for each button

```
board1_placeX():
    board1.config(text='X') #changes only one of them

board2_placeX():
    board2.config(text='Y')

...and so on, define 9 of these, and another nine for placeO(), like board1_placeO() and so on
```

and when you define board button, use specific function for example if i define board one i will use board1_placeX()/board1_placeO()

```
board1 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "1", command = lambda:[board1_placeX(), board1_placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
board1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

and for board 2...

```
board2 = tk.Button(gameWindow, text = "1", command = lambda:[board2_placeX(), board2_placeO()], height = 10, width = 20)
board2.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

...and so on. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use the sample way with lambda like this:

```
test_button = Button(text="your_text_button", command=lambda:[placeX(),placeO()])
```